# Apply CSS style to all columns of a table

Tags: css

In my CSS, I have an entry:

```
.isenabled {
    font-weight:bold; 
    background-color:lightyellow
}
```

In the HTML, I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="isenabled">This is enabled</td>
        <td>This isn't</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works as intended.  What I'd like to do is:

```
<table>
    <tr class="isenabled">
        <td>This is enabled</td>
        <td>So is this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="isenabled">This is enabled</td>
        <td>This isn't</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But this doesn't work as it stands (both the cells have the default background).  What should I do instead?

[EDIT]
I've made the desired behaviour more explicit.

Comment: do you want to highlight first column particular row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following style

```css
tr.isenabled > td, td.isenabled {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightyellow
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="isenabled">
    <td>This is enabled</td>
    <td>So is this</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works for the whole row, but it no longer works for the individual cells.  I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

.isenabled is catching the element with class "isenabled".

that's why when you add class to 'td' it works.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="isenabled">This is enabled</td>
        <td>This isn't</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if you are adding class to 'tr' element the css properties will be applied to 'tr' but you want it to be applied on 'td'.

'>' is used for immediate child after the the selected element

so if you write "tr > td" as selected it will select all 'td' which are immediate child of any 'tr' in html document.

so you can do like this

```
tr.isenabled > td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightyellow
}
```

it will select all 'td' which is immediate child of any element with class "isenabled".

Here is the more information about css selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.